# error installing npm@1.1.1 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I am trying to get going with express framework on Mac OS X Lion.  Having these issues:

```
SilverFir-2:Node mike$ sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7881  100  7881    0     0  29556      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43541
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
install npm@1.1
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.1.1.tgz
0.6.1
1.1.1
cleanup prefix=/usr/local

All clean!
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___npm.npm
npm ERR! error installing npm@1.1.1

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/6x/frvx23td327frc2z_hgl12sc0000gn/T/npm.3230/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/6x/frvx23td327frc2z_hgl12sc0000gn/T/npm.3230/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/6x/frvx23td327frc2z_hgl12sc0000gn/T/npm.3230/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
It failed
```

Node version v0.6.1.

I looked around on the web and most of the answers are from node 0.4 days and they all just say upgrade.  It looks like I am more up to date than those previous questions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

You will run `curl` as `root`, but `sh` as your current user. You should do this instead:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

And all will be well.