# Error when using npm

Tags: node.js, titanium, npm

I get the following error when trying to use npm on mac. I'm on mac 10.10.1

```
$ npm
Error: ENAMETOOLONG, mkdir '/Users/LM/npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'config',
npm verb cli   'get',
npm verb cli   'prefix' ]
npm info using npm@2.1.6
npm info using node@v0.10.33
npm verb node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
/Users/LM/Desktop/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'config',
npm verb cli   'get',
npm verb cli   'prefix' ]
npm info using npm@2.1.6
npm info using node@v0.10.33
npm verb node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
/Users/LM/Desktop/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'config',
npm verb cli   'get',
npm verb cli   'prefix' ]
npm info using npm@2.1.6
npm info using node@v0.10.33
npm verb node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok'
```

Any ideas what this means and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to the permissions. Try to change the permissions as followed :

1. Unlock permissions in your home directory.

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
   ```
2. If 1 does not work, get write permissions to the `node_modules` directory.

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
   ```
3. If you still face error, update permission of `/usr/local`.

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no `.npm` in ~. Run other commands but same problem.

Comment: if you still face the error, try to uninstall all node and npm instances and install fresh via [brew](http://thechangelog.com/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x/) or via [curl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9377023/3419997).

Comment: what is the version of node and npm you have ?

Comment: As it is shown from the log npm version is 2.1.6 and node version os 0.10.33

Answer (score 0):

The error ENAMETOOLONG means that nodejs (or the OS) is trying to use a pathname component that exceeds your OS's maximum (in the case of OSX, 31).

Firstly where have you tried to install nodejs from? This could be the cause of your issue. I've never used Titanium Studio but your question reads like this is the intall of nodejs that you are using.

You may be best installing node directly from github. The following should get you started.

### Install Node

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.10.33
mkdir ~/local

./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
make
make install
```

Dont forget to add $HOME/local/node/bin to your PATH enviromental variable.
You can test your node installation by

```
node -v
```

### Install NPM

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

You can test your npm installation by

```
npm -v
```

Comment: I have tried to install node from homebrew and via the package downloaded from nodejs website. Neither fixed the problem.

Comment: Could you give me the output of the following 2 commands "which node" and "which npm"

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions suggested here, where somebody has the exact same problem, also using titanium studio: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/179230/unable-to-properly-update-titanium-studio

- Manually updating CLI, Node.ACS, and Alloy

  sudo npm install -g alloy@1.5.1
  sudo npm install -g titanium@3.4.1
  sudo npm install -g acs
- Change permissions to the directory

  sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm

Although it seems that the last thing did not work. You might want to have a look here as well: [NPM throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451)

Comment: If you are using -g you are installing into the system path, not in the homedir folder of `whoami`.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Discover where `npm` executables exist

First, find out where `npm` executables exist on your system:

```
$ which -a npm
```

This should output two or more system paths.

#### 2. Find out your shell's `$PATH`

Then, determine the search paths for your command execution:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

This will give you a colon-separated list of directories your session is searching for executables like `npm`.

#### 3. Give priority to a different `npm`

Appcelerator Titanium has corrupted one or more aspects of your system. You may want to temporarily uninstall Titanium.

Otherwise, to give preference to another Node.js installation, you can edit your `$PATH` or even more simply, create a shell `alias`. For example:

```
$ alias npm=/usr/local/bin/npm
```

In most cases, you can "save" this in your `~/.bash_profile` file (by simply copying and pasting the text as if you were at the prompt) so that it's applied to future shell sessions.